# create a dict of dict from dict of lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

I have a python object which is a dict of keys being hostnames and values being a list of users and their disk usage in the notation of dicts. I have pasted my dict below as the explanation seems confusing. Each host is a key and under each host there might be several users which are common in the hosts and which might be unique too. I am struggling to check the following conditions.

1. Check if that user exists in each host.
2. If yes, add the total disk he is utilising in each host.
3. If not, append the unique user to the dict.
4. Now in the big dict sort the users in the order of their disk usage.

Achieved so far:
1. Log in to each of the hosts
2. Get the users and their disk usage
3. result is stored in a dict with hostnames as keys and values is a list of users and their disk usage.

If I can make this a dict of dict, I hope my problem is solved.

```
{
'localhost': [
    'alice: 1491916K',
    'bob: 423576K'
],
'10.252.136.241': [
    'alice: 3491916K',
    'bob: 4235K',
    'chaplin: 3456K'
]
}
```

This is a sample output from 2 hosts. Now I have the result object which is a dict in the above form. I want to iterate to each of the host, see if the user 'alice' exists in each host and add his disk space and have a single entry in the dict for 'alice' and the same for 'bob' and then leave  'chaplin' as is in the new dict. I dont want host specific. I want a total usage at the end.

I am just stuck at iterating. I can manage to sum up and create the big dict of 'user': 'total_space' once I can iterate.

**[UPDATE]**
My expected output is

```
expected_output = { 'alice': '498382K', 'bob': '427811K', 'chaplin': '3456K' }
```

Here. The usage of alice is being added in each of the hosts. same for bob and chaplin is just appended because he is not present in all the hosts.

Comment: Please show an example of your required output.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added my expected output in the update of the question. Thx

Comment: Well, iterating isn't the hardest thing here any more; now you also seem to want to parse the values to integers and sum them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
given_dict = {
    'localhost': ['alice: 1491916K', 'bob: 423576K'],
    '10.252.136.241': ['alice: 3491916K', 'bob: 4235K', 'chaplin: 3456K']
}
resultant_dict = {}

for values in given_dict.values():
    for value in values:
        name, usage = value.split(':')
        usage = int(usage.strip().rstrip('K'))
        if name in resultant_dict:
            resultant_dict[name] += usage
        else:
            resultant_dict[name] = usage

sorted_result = sorted(resultant_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
for name, usage in sorted_result:
    print("{}: {}".format(name, usage))
```

Would give you this output

```
chaplin: 3456
bob: 427811
alice: 4983832
```

If you're looking to sort the result in the descending order of disk usage, set `reverse=True` for the `sorted` function.

Answer (score 1):

For this task you can use combination of such tools as [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
values = {
'localhost': [
    'alice: 1491916K',
    'bob: 423576K'
],
'10.252.136.241': [
    'alice: 3491916K',
    'bob: 4235K',
    'chaplin: 3456K'
]
}
import re
import itertools

numbers = re.compile(r'\d+')

parsed_list = [(el.split(': ')[0], int(numbers.findall(el)[0])) for k, v in values.items() for el in v]

print({k: sum([el[1] for el in v]) for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(parsed_list), key=lambda x: x[0])})
```

Output:

```
{'alice': 4983832, 'bob': 427811, 'chaplin': 3456}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

This is naive implementation for algorithm which turns `list` in to `dict` expecting the format you've shown.

```
In [21]: def dictify(l):
    ...:     d = dict()
    ...:     for x in l:
    ...:         key, val = [y.strip() for y in x.split(':')]
    ...:         d[key] = val
    ...:     return d
In [22]: dictify(data['localhost'])
Out[22]: {'alice': '1491916K', 'bob': '423576K'}
```

Comment: Thanks much for this. I am still failing to do a list comprehension to make a list of all the dicts and the idea is to further use collections.Counter and sum up the values of corresponding keys in all the dicts and make a single dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
import re

dic = {
    'localhost': [
        'alice: 1491916K',
        'bob: 423576K'
    ],
    '10.252.136.241': [
        'alice: 3491916K',
        'bob: 4235K',
        'chaplin: 3456K'
    ],
}

users = {}
# down we are unpacking all the names/vals of (['alice', ' 3491916K'], ['bob', ' 4235K'], ['chaplin', ' 3456K'], ['alice', ' 1491916K'], ['bob', ' 423576K'])
for name, val in (j.split(':') for x in dic.values() for j in x):
    users[name] = users.get(name, 0) + int(re.findall('\d+', val)[0])

print(users) # {'chaplin': 3456, 'alice': 4983832, 'bob': 427811}
sort_users = sorted(users.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(sort_users) # [('alice', 4983832), ('bob', 427811), ('chaplin', 3456)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data={
'localhost': [
    'alice: 1491916K',
    'bob: 423576K'
],
'10.252.136.241': [
    'alice: 3491916K',
    'bob: 4235K',
    'chaplin: 3456K'
]
}

res=[]
k=data.values()
for elm in k:
    res1={}
    for x in elm:
        res1[(x.split(':'))[0]]=x.split(':')[1]
    res.append(res1)

print dict(zip(data.keys(), res))
```

Output :

```
{'10.252.136.241': {'chaplin': ' 3456K', 'bob': ' 4235K', 'alice': ' 3491916K'}, 'localhost': {'bob': ' 423576K', 'alice': ' 1491916K'}}
```